# Not getting correct output through recursive procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a table called 'test_table'. It has two columns named 'parent' and 'child' as below:
    Assuming both columns are of Varchar2 type.

```
    PARENT    CHILD
    ---------------------
    50-100    10-001
    50-100    10-002
    50-100    10-003
    50-100    11-100
    50-100    11-101
    11-100    10-100
    11-100    10-101
    11-100    10-102
```

I need to write a recursive procedure in such a way that if child for given parent starts with '10' then it will be printed.
If child value starts with '11' then the procedure will be called recursively for each child values starting with 11.
Below is the sample output required:

```
CHILD
--------------
10-001
10-002
10-003
10-100
10-101
10-102
```

This is the sample procedure:

```
create or replace type type_test2 as table of varchar2(2000);

create or replace procedure test_proc
     (parent_data in type_test2,child_data out type_test2)
as 
    v_out type_test2:=type_test2();
    begin
      child_data:=type_test2();
      select child 
      bulk collect into v_out 
      from test_table 
      where parent in(select * from table(parent_data));

      for i in 1..v_out.count loop

        child_data.extend(i);
        v_out.extend(i);

        if v_out(i) like '10-%' then
           child_data(i):=v_out(I);
        elsif v_out(i) like '11-%' then
           test_proc(v_out,child_data);
        end if;

    end loop;
 end;
/
```

Executing the above procedure:

```
    declare
        a type_test2:=type_test2('50-100');
        b type_test2:=type_test2();
    begin
        test_proc(a,b);
        for i in 1..b.count loop
            dbms_output.put_line(b(I));
        end loop;
    end;
 /
```

But I am getting only 5 child values instead of 6 values.*'10-100' is missing.*

```
        Child
        ---------------
        10-102
        10-101
        10-003
        10-002
        10-001
```

Kindly help me in getting the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Don't recursively call the procedure; instead use a single hierarchical query:

**Procedure**:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test_proc (
  i_parent   IN  test_table.parent%TYPE,
  o_children OUT type_test2
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT CHILD
  BULK COLLECT INTO o_children
  FROM   test_table
  WHERE  CHILD like '10-%'
  START WITH parent = i_parent
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
         PRIOR child = parent
  AND    PRIOR child LIKE '11-%';
END;
/
```

**Executing**:

```sql
DECLARE
  b type_test2:=type_test2();
BEGIN
  test_proc( '50-100', b );
  FOR i IN 1..b.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( b(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
 /
```

**Output**:

> ```
> 10-001
> 10-002
> 10-003
> 10-100
> 10-101
> 10-102
> ```

**Alternate**:

You don't even need a procedure and could do it all in a single query:

```sql
SELECT CHILD
FROM   test_table
WHERE  CHILD like '10-%'
START WITH parent = '50-100'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR child = parent
AND    PRIOR child LIKE '11-%';
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | CHILD  |
> | :----- |
> | 10-001 |
> | 10-002 |
> | 10-003 |
> | 10-100 |
> | 10-101 |
> | 10-102 |
> ```

---

> why we are not getting correct output with the recursive procedure.

Each time you use `BULK COLLECT INTO` it reinitialises the collection it is outputting to and overwrites the previous values. You need to `BULK COLLECT INTO` a different collection and then merge the two if you want to retain the previous values.

Something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc(
  parent_data IN  type_test2,
  child_data  OUT type_test2
)
AS 
  v_to_search      type_test2;
  v_search_results type_test2;
  i PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT child
  BULK COLLECT INTO child_data 
  FROM   test_table 
  WHERE  parent MEMBER OF parent_data
  AND    child LIKE '10-%';

  SELECT child
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_to_search 
  FROM   test_table 
  WHERE  parent MEMBER OF parent_data
  AND    child LIKE '11-%';

  IF v_to_search.COUNT = 0 THEN
    RETURN;
  END IF;
  test_proc( v_to_search, v_search_results );
  i := child_data.COUNT;
  child_data.EXTEND( v_search_results.COUNT );
  FOR j IN 1 .. v_search_results.COUNT LOOP
    child_data(i+j) := v_search_results(j);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

However, that can get stuck in an infinite loop if there is a cycle in your data. The hierarchical query above will detect cycles and stop iterating (or if you remove the `NOCYCLE` keyword would raise an exception).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=517b5978ce912d523ee884f427e4f2ea)*

Comment: One query-why we are not getting correct output with the recursive procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
How can we avoid the infinite loop in the above procedure?

Comment: @Rohan Use a hierarchical query instead of the procedure as its going to be more efficient and use the `NOCYCLE` keyword to detect and prevent cycles. If you insist on using a recursive procedure then you will need to manually add some code to detect the cycles before you recurse into them; you'll probably need to pass the children found at each level into the recursive procedure and filter to eliminate the previous results from the descendant's results but I think you'd do better asking a new question if you want to explore that further.